# Can Jersey defined web services return not known subclasses?

Tags: json, web-services, polymorphism, jersey-2.0

I want to build a web **utility module** that exposes some web services using Jersey 2.0 and Jackson 2.2.

One of the web services has to return a list of `AbstractType`'s. The web application that uses the utility modules defines and will provide some `ConcreteType`'s objects. This concrete type is defined this way:

```
public class ConcreteType extends AbstractType
{
  public int getPropertyDefinedInThisConcreteType()
  {
    return 0;
  }   
}
```

if I define the web service method like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<? extends AbstractType> getAbstractTypeObjects()
{
  List<? extends AbstractType> concreteTypes = findConcreteTypeFromWebApp();
  return concreteTyypes;
}
```

the JSON record that is produced by Jersey contains only the properties from `AbstractType` and does not serialize the `propertyDefinedInThisConcreteType` property.

But if I change the method above and write:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ConcreteType> getAbstractTypeObjects()
{
  List<? extends AbstractType> concreteTypes = findConcreteTypeFromWebApp();
  return concreteTyypes;
}
```

the JSON record produced includes now the property from the `ConcreteType` class.

Is there any way for defining a web service in the utility module that could return any concrete type defined in and provided by any application that uses that module without knowing this concrete type at compile time? Or the only way is to define the web service in the web application that knows about the concrete type?

In other words is Jersey polymorphism aware?

---

To try to clarify my question if a run the following program:

```
public class JacksonTest
{
  static abstract class AbstractType
  {
    public int getPropertyDefinedInAbstractType_1()
    {
      return 1;
    }
    public int getPropertyDefinedInAbstractType_2()
    {
      return 2;
    }
  }

  static class ConcreteType extends AbstractType
  {
    public int getPropertyDefinedInThisConcreteType()
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<? extends AbstractType> abstractTypes = getAbstractTypes();
    String serialize = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(abstractTypes);
    System.out.println(serialize);
  }

  static List<? extends AbstractType> getAbstractTypes()
  {
    List<AbstractType> abstractTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    abstractTypes.add(new ConcreteType());
    abstractTypes.add(new ConcreteType());
    return abstractTypes;
  }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "propertyDefinedInThisConcreteType":0,
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_1":1,
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_2":2
  },
  {
    "propertyDefinedInThisConcreteType":0,
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_1":1,
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_2":2
  }
]
```

but Jersey when calling this web service method

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<? extends AbstractType> getAbstractTypeObjects()
{
  List<? extends AbstractType> abstractTypes = getAbstractTypes();
  return abstractTypes;
}
```

produces:

```
[
  {
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_1":1,
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_2":2
  },
  {
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_1":1,
    "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_2":2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Jackson polymorphism, e.g look into the annotations @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonTypeName/@JsonSubTypes

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: I edited my original question to clarify what my problem is. I don't want to add type information to my JSON output as your answer suggests. What I want is **to get all the properties** of my object when **serializing** it.

Answer (score 1):

This is odd behavior, in which I cannot explain, but while playing around with it, I was able to reproduce the problem. What is odd though, is that to correct the behavior, I had to return `Response` instead of `List<? extends AbstractType>`

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAbstractTypeObjects() {

    List<? extends AbstractType> concreteTypes = getAbstractTypes();
    return Response.ok(concreteTypes).build();
}

static List<? extends AbstractType> getAbstractTypes() {
    List<AbstractType> abstractTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    abstractTypes.add(new ConcreteType());
    abstractTypes.add(new ConcreteType());
    return abstractTypes;
}
```

> `C:\>curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/types`
>   `[ {
>     "propertyDefinedInThisConcreteType" : 0,
>     "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_1" : 1,
>     "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_2" : 2
>   }, {
>     "propertyDefinedInThisConcreteType" : 0,
>     "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_1" : 1,
>     "propertyDefinedInAbstractType_2" : 2
>   } ]`

and it works fine. Like I said, I can't really explain the reason for this beahavior :-(

My **guess** is tha returning `Response` causes the properties to be discovered, while return `AbstractType` causes only the properties of `AbstractType` to be used.

Answer (score 0):

After reading both answers above and experimented for a while I think that I can post an answer to my question.

I noticed that if I define the web service method as:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<? extends Object> getAbstractTypeObjects()
{
  ...
}
```

the complete ConcreteType object is also outputted.

It seems that Jersey guarantees to the web service clients that the properties they will receive will be compatible with the return type declared. But if you declare `Object` as the return type all the properties are included in the JSON register. I don't know if all this is in the specification.

In the case that you use `@JsonTypeInfo` in the `AbstractType` class all the properties of the `ConcreteType` object are always sent independently of the return type declared in the web service. The problem with that approach is that you need to have access to the `ConcreteType` class, because the type info is also encoded in the JSON output. If not using `@JsonTypeInfo` you can declare another class in the client side that has the same properties that class actually sent for receiving the web service output.

If you try to use `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NONE)` in the declaration of the `AbstractType` class to avoid this last inconvenience then the `ConcreteType` properties are again not outputted.